# Use comma delimited string from query in subquery

Tags: mysql, variables, subquery, in-subquery

I would like to use comma delimited ID string as an input into the same query.

i.e:

```
Set @IDs := '';

Select @IDs := CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(`id` as CHAR)) AS Char) AS 'ID String',
(
 Select FORMAT(Sum(`Quantity`),0)
 from 'My Table'
 Where `ID` IN (@IDs)
 ) As 'Quantity'

From `My Table`
```

The actual query is much more complicated, but what I need to achieve is to assign comma delimited ID string to variable and use that string in sub-query withing the IN clause.

The above is not working. I would appreciate any feedback.

Thank you!

Comment: Why can you cast the id's as int types instead of chars? This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What MySQL sees is a string value.  It doesn't interpret that value as a list of values, even if the string contains commas.

Let's explain this by way of an example:

```
 SET @bar = 'fee,fi,fo,fum';
 SELECT * FROM mytable t WHERE t.foo IN (@bar) ;
```

That's equivalent to

```
 SELECT * FROM mytable t WHERE t.foo = 'fee,fi,fo,fum'
```

MySQL is going to see `@bar` as a single value. It doesn't matter that it contains one or more commas, it's just a string literal; it isn't interpreted as SQL text. Those commas are just characters in a string.

---

One workaround to this limitation is to use "dynamic SQL", which would allow you to execute an arbitrary string as a SQL statement. You can construct/concatenate together whatever text you want into a variable, and then execute the contents of the variable as if it were a SQL statement (within a MySQL stored procedure. Your use case would require multiple statements. But be *very* careful with this approach, because this can potentially open the code to some nefarious SQL Injection vulnerabilities.)  I'm not going to give an example, because I don't see that the problem you are trying to solve warrants that level of complexity.

---

It looks like the query in the question is attempting to return a result equivalent to this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.id) AS `ID String`
     , FORMAT(SUM(t.quantity),0)   AS `Quantity`
  FROM `My Table` t
 WHERE t.id IS NOT NULL
```

---

Be aware that there's a *limit* on the length of the string returned by the `GROUP_CONCAT` function (the setting of the `group_concat_max_len` variable, and the `max_allowed_packet` variable). If the limit is exceeded, MySQL doesn't issue any error or warning, it completes successfully, returning a string truncated to the maximum allowed length.

It's not at all clear why a subquery would be needed, or why you'd need to check if value of the `id` column is one of the values included in the "list" of ids returned by `GROUP_CONCAT` function. (Perhaps there is something in the specification that I'm not understanding.)

Comment: Thank you Spencer. Very detailed answer. I used Dynamic SQL, prepared statements in stored procedure and everything works just fine. Query execution dropped from around 9 seconds to just below 1. Edited  group_concat_max_len and max_allowed_packet variable just in case as well. as for the safety, procedure in called from within C# code which is completely managed, so I don;t foresee any risk of SQL injection. Thanks again.